# How to combine two SQL queries being performed on the same tables into one?

Tags: mysql

Below are the 2 queries I need to combine into one, and I like to have rows from the left table even if there is no matching row in the right table.

```
                    $sql = "SELECT country.printable_name FROM sku"
                    . "LEFT OUTER JOIN country ON country.numcode=sku.c_code"
                    . "WHERE sku.item_sku='JDJ2020'";

                   $sql= "SELECT hs_code FROM hs_codes"
                   . "INNER JOIN sku ON 
                   sku.base_category=hs_codes.base_category AND 
                   sku.sub_category=hs_codes.sub_category"
                   . "WHERE sku.item_sku = 'JDJ2020'";
```

Comment: *Below are the 2 queries* This is PHP code, not SQL code. Provide pure SQL (after some definite `$vendor_sku` insertion). PS. 2nd query is INNER JOIN by fact - why LEFT joining is written?

Comment: Thanks, edited the query as advised. Please check it out.

Comment: This is PHP code again. Provide not it but the value of `$sql` variable obtained only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After PHP code clearing the queries will look like

```sql
SELECT country.printable_name 
FROM sku
LEFT OUTER JOIN country ON country.numcode=sku.c_code
WHERE sku.item_sku='JDJ2020';

SELECT hs_code 
FROM hs_codes
INNER JOIN sku ON sku.base_category=hs_codes.base_category 
              AND sku.sub_category=hs_codes.sub_category
WHERE sku.item_sku = 'JDJ2020';
```

Their combining may look like

```sql
SELECT country.printable_name, hs_codes.hs_code
FROM sku
INNER JOIN hs_codes ON sku.base_category=hs_codes.base_category 
                   AND sku.sub_category=hs_codes.sub_category
LEFT OUTER JOIN country ON sku.c_code=country.numcode
WHERE sku.item_sku='JDJ2020';
```

If there exists a row in the `country` which matches the row in `sku` **always** then replace `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

If there exists more than one matched row in `country` and/or `hs_codes` then you'll obtain more than one output row.